# Who *really* wrote the Rama sequels?

Tags: arthur-c-clarke, authors, rendezvous-with-rama, rama-revealed

The Rama sequels, starting with Rama II and on, are co-authored by Arthur C. Clarke and Gentry Lee.

I'm wondering if there are any sources (e.g., interviews) discussing Clarke's impact or contribution to these books, as their style is very similar to Lee's later standalone series (bright messengers/double full moon night).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. DavRob seems to give an official quote.

I do find it strange though since the style is almost identical, and the obsession with certain themes (such as incest) which is very pronounced in Lee's standalone novels exist also in the later Ramas

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's Gentry Lee that wrote them, Clarke was more a consultant than an author on those books :

> Since then Gentry has collaborated on Rama II and The Garden of Rama, and Rama Revealed, **which was written virtually entirely by him, though with consultation with me**. I've described our collaboration in the preface, "Co-Authors and Other Nuisances," I think in Rama II.
>
> [Arthur C. Clarke Remembers A Lifetime Of Influences In A Science-fictional World: www.syfy.co.uk](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1685/who-really-wrote-the-rama-sequels)

Comment: The link redirects to this very question - did you mean to quote [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/67338/98028) instead?

Answer (score 11):

Whenever you see a book that is attributed to "<famous author> & <relative unknown>", it's safe to assume that the relative unknown did most or all of the writing.

Comment: That's what I suspect as well, especially considering the context and the weirder parts of both books.

Comment: References to back up that statistical hypothesis?

Comment: Unless somebody provides citations to actual research, you can assume that 43.9% of their statistics are made up on the spot.